# can't find variable : firebase

Tags: firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to link my firestore with my currentuser . Everything was working until i add the firebase.auth().

I have an error can't find variable: firebase

also my function :

```
createUser = () => {
      firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
        if (user) {
            // User is signed in.
            firestore()
        .collection('Users')
        .add({
            NickName: this.state.NickName,
            Age: this.state.Age,
            City:this.state.City,
            Mail:this.state.Mail,
            MyTeam:[{
                Activity:"",
                City:"",
                Members:[{
                    Mail:"",
                    Pseudo:""
                }],
            Owner:true
            }]
        
            }).then ( ()=>{ }
               
            )
                .then(() => {
                    this.props.navigation.navigate('Profil')
                
                })
                
        } else {
            // No user is signed in.
            console.log('coucou')
        }});
           
                
    }
```

Also my import :

```
import React, {Component, useState, useEffect} from 'react';



import {
  View,
  Text,
  TouchableOpacity,
  Image,
  TextInput,
  Link,
  SafeAreaView,
  
  Animated,
} from 'react-native';
import auth from '@react-native-firebase/auth';

import { GoogleSignin } from '@react-native-community/google-signin';
import { Button } from 'react-native-ios-kit';
import firestore from  '@react-native-firebase/firestore'
```

The function was working well without the firebase.auth() did i do something wrong ?

Answer (score 3):

It seems like you didn’t import firebase

```
import * as firebase from 'firebase';
```